# How to use spread operator to test if a list of objects are present in a word?

Tags: javascript

```
const [reserveWords, setReservedWords]=({
word1 = 'password',
word2 = 'firstName'})

const reservedWordCheck = (password) =>{
password.includes(...reserveWords);
```

i am stuck here, im not sure what else to do here
I am trying to test the password to make sure it does not contain any of the reserve words

Comment: includes() is a function of the array. `['word1','word2'].includes('word1'); //=>true` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: I think you need `Object.values(reserveWords).includes(password)`. Also objects are written like this `{word1:'password', word2: 'firstname'}` (no = sign)

Comment: Your variable initialization (`[reserveWords, setReserveWords]`) is wrong, it will give you a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 1):

`includes` take a `searchElement` parameter. You can't spread the object to become a function argument. If an array, spreading an array would just mean you're passing all the items in the array to the function. But that function only takes a single parameter. What you can do is loop through each word in an array.

```js
const reservedWordCheck = (password, reservedWords) => reservedWords.some(word => password.includes(word));

const reservedWords = ['hello', 'world'];

console.log(reservedWordCheck('helloworld', reservedWords));
console.log(reservedWordCheck('validpassword', reservedWords));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable initialization (`const ...`) is wrong.

Furthermore, array extensions like `includes`, `map`, `some` expect a function as (first) argument to execute on each element of the underlying array, so you can't use the spread operator there.

If you want to check if a word is present within an array (here: of objects), [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) may do the job. Something like:

```js
const [words, checkPass, checkNameAndPass] = [ 
  [ {word1: 'password', word2: 'firstName'},
    {word1: 'password1', word2: 'firstName1'},
    {word1: 'password2', word2: 'firstName2'},
    {word1: 'password3', word2:  'firstName3'}, ], 
  word => words.find( w => w.word1 === word ) ? true : false,
  (name, pass) => words.find(w => w.word2 === name && w.word1 === pass) 
    ? true : false 
];

console.log(`checkPass('password2') => ${checkPass('password2')}`);
console.log(`checkNameAndPass('firstName3', 'password3') => ${
  checkNameAndPass(`firstName3`, `password3`)}`);
console.log(`checkNameAndPass('firstName1', 'password3') => ${
  checkNameAndPass(`firstName1`, 'password3')}`);
  
// spread operator usage
const checkPasswordAndName = (...args) => {
  const [pass, name] = args; // <=
  return words.find(v => v.word1 === pass && v.word2 === name)
    ? true : false;
};

console.log(`checkPasswordAndName('password1', 'firstName1') => ${
  checkPasswordAndName('password1', 'firstName1')}` );
console.log(`checkPasswordAndName('nope', 'no way') => ${
  checkPasswordAndName('nope', 'no way')}` );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```